# Xamarin Android app has ambigous references by default

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

There seems to be an issue with Xamarin Android projects (at least on my machine) with references.

[image: Ambiguous references]

This is just the default project code that comes already written when you create a new Xamarin Android project, so I didn't change anything. I checked what two different files it's references and it's grabbing the code from the `obj` folder in addition to the original code. I already tried restarting VS, cleaning and rebuilding the solution, and creating another project in a different folder but still getting the same reference errors.

Comment: Delete  bin and obj, restart VS. BTW, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50593906/ambiguous-reference-intellisense-error-from-resource-designer-cs) is similar with your question.

Comment: I provided a solution to a similar question a couple days ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50593906/ambiguous-reference-intellisense-error-from-resource-designer-cs/50673004#50673004).  BTW, I don't think I have enough Reputation yet to mark this question as a duplicate, but hopefully someone else can if that's appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Robert's answer (from a different post) is correct. I simply updated ReSharper and everything went back to normal.

You can find his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50593906/ambiguous-reference-intellisense-error-from-resource-designer-cs/50673004#50673004).