# Resource is an ambiguous reference

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and Xamarin. The part where I am getting error is:

```
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    FormsAppCompatActivity.ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
    FormsAppCompatActivity.TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;

    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    Forms.Init(this, bundle);
    LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

The error i am getting is `'Resource' is an ambiguous reference between 'Plugin.MediaManager.Forms.Android.Resource' and 'SegmentedControl.FormsPlugin.Android.Resource'` the issue is, I am following the guide on their official site https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/ So, I think it must be something related to my setup of visual studio. How can i fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ambiguous reference intellisense error from Resource.Designer.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50593906/ambiguous-reference-intellisense-error-from-resource-designer-cs)

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't working on Mac VS2017, then you can try this:

1. Put bellow property to your csproj

   ```
   <AndroidUseManagedDesignTimeResourceGenerator>False</AndroidUseManagedDesignTimeResourceGenerator>
   ```
2. Clean and rebuild your project

I hope it can help you.