# 'Resource.Designer.cs' keeps old namespace after it has been changed throughout entire solution

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

At some point project identity was modified and i reflected that in code by renaming the solution, project, assembly and default namespace, with all corresponding folders - all instances of a name that i could find.  I also used Notepad2 to fix the contents of solution and project files.
[image: Project Properties - Application tab]
Note: Namespace in code was changed using VStudio's Rename feature.

Since then every time `Resource.Designer.cs` file gets re-generated, it pulls the old namespace in (?!), breaking the reference to automatic `Resource` class, which defines resource IDs:
[image: Resource.Designer.cs - auto-generated]

Obviously, i try to fix this:
[image: Resource.Designer.cs - edited]

And in some cases it will immediately get re-generated again - you guessed it - with the old name, but *sometimes*(!) it will accept my edit, save it and let the project be actually compiled and run:
[image: Compilation happily on the merry way!]

I've tried Clean and Rebuild commands multiple times for both project and solution, restarted VStudio, rebooted Windows..  No dice, it keeps happening.

App's TargetPlatform is 7.1, MinimumVersion is 4.3, all 5 supported architectures are enabled.  VStudio - 15.5.4, .NET - 4.7.03056, Xamarin - 4.8.0.757, Xamarin.Android SDK - 8.1.3.0.

Just found this in the Similar Questions list:
[Ambiguous reference intellisense error from Resource.Designer.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50593906).  Looked promising, so i did the following:

1. Closed solution in VisualStudio.
2. Removed entirely `\bin` and `\obj` subfolders in File Explorer.
3. Edited `Resource.Designer.cs`, so it has correct (new) namespace:  J7987ca.
4. Added 'AndroidUseManagedDesignTimeResourceGenerator' to `J7987ca.csproj`, as advised.
5. Opened the solution, and here's the result - **old namespace is back**:
   [image: Re-opening solution after purging \bin and \obj subfolders]

I guess, i can start with a clean slate and re-create entire solution from scratch with a new name, but for the Love of God, *why do i have to do that*?  And **where does it pull the old name from**?!

Comment: Clean bin obj in the android project, then Delete the ResourceDesigner.cs file from the solution and then clean build the solution and it will work. Oh yeah the old names come from the bin and obj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My last image shows `<RootNamespace>J7980ca</RootNamespace>` - the old name.  I did not pay much attention to re-check that tab after re-opening solution, because such an awful glitch would never occure to me:  i never had problems saving values in those VS "dialogs" previously.

It turns out that **changing Default Namespace in Project Properties does not take effect**!
I verified it twice.

Mind you, Assembly Name was saved, so i'm at a loss of wits to explain, how all this is happening.

As soon as i edited `.csproj` in Notepad2 re-opening the solution happily put proper namespace into `Resources.Designer.cs` and allowed compilation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to this, but I ran into this issue recently and was able to fix it by updating both `<RootNamespace>` and `<AssemblyName>` tags in the Android `csproj` file.

Then cleaning the `sln` and closing Visual Studio and deleting `bin`, `obj`, and the old `Resource.Designer.cs` file (from the directory using the File Explorer and not by removing it from the `csproj`).

Answer (score 0):

You also need to change it in the assembly line, not just the namespace.

For example

[assembly: global::Android.Runtime.ResourceDesignerAttribute("com.companyname.TestBottomSheetDialog.Resource", IsApplication=true)]

namespace com.companyname.TestBottomSheetDialog